# Resetting dask dataframe index to allow join

Tags: dask

Given http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.reset_index says dask doesn't support `drop=True` for `reset_index()` how do I join 2 dataframes together with different index (as viewed by `head()`)

Comment: Are you familiar with the `left_on=` and `right_on=` keyword arguments to `pd.merge`?

Comment: I wasn't but would that work if the keys were different in both data frame?

Comment: You may find the Pandas documentation useful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

Answer (score 0):

While my dask dataframe was small I was able to create a pandas dataframe from it, reset the index by dropping it

```
npdf = ddSample.compute()
npdf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
npdf.head()
```

after that I was able to use

```
ddmerged= dd.merge(npdf,df2)
```